# Android on Eclipse: no Wi-Fi 3G or Edge connection detected

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm using a third party compiled .jar library, and I can't get it working on my Android 2.2 project with Eclipse. Looking in the LogCat, I see that there is an exception thrown after this debug message:

```
NO WIFI, 3G or Edge connection detected
```

from the third party library. So it seems at some point there is a check on the connection being used and the connection used by the Android emulator is not found.

How can I fix this? Is there some option on the emulator to make its connection looks like a 3G or a Wi-Fi one to Android?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the connection may be blocked by your firewall if you're using one.

Take a look at this section on [Emulator Networking](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) to see if it helps you.

Network emulation obviously needs to use an existing ethernet connection so that basically must be open for you to use it.

Comment: internet IS working inside the emulator. the problem is that "that internet" its not recognised as 3G connection nor WI-FI.